# Trim Non-alphanum from beginning and end of string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

what is the best way to trim ALL non alpha numeric characters from the beginning and end of a string ? I tried to add characters that I do no need manually but it doesn't work well and use the . I just need to trim anything not alphanumeric.

I tried using this function:

```
   string something = "()&*1@^#47*^#21%Littering aaaannnndóú(*&^1#*32%#**)7(#9&^";
   string somethingNew = Regex.Replace(something, @"[^\p{L}-\s]+", "");
```

But it removes all characters that are non alpha numeric from the string. What I basically want is like this:

```
"test1" -> test1
#!@!2test# -> 2test
(test3) -> test3
@@test4---- -> test4
```

I do want to support unicode characters but not symbols..

EDIT:
The output of the example should be:

```
Littering aaaannnndóú
```

Regards

Comment: I suspect you mean `#!@!2test -> 2test` not `#!@!2test -> test` in your second example of what you want.  Dropping the `2` is inconsistent with the other examples and your description of what you want.

Comment: Yes I am sorry I just edited it

Comment: @circler You still show dropping the leading '2' in your second example.  Please explain the logic of that since '2' is a numeric character

Comment: @J0e3gan I updated it again

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to trim non-alphanumeric characters from the start and end of your string:

```
s = new string(s.SkipWhile(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
                .TakeWhile(char.IsLetterOrDigit)
                .ToArray());
```

Comment: I want to remove both non alphanum from the start & from the end. I just edited the examples

Answer (score 1):

`@"[^\p{L}\s-]+(test\d*)|(test\d*)[^\p{L}\s-]+","$1`"

Comment: "test" was an example string only

Answer (score 0):

You can use String function `String.Trim Method (Char[])` in `.NET` library to trim the unnecessary characters from the given string.

**From MSDN :** [`String.Trim Method (Char[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Removes all leading and trailing occurrences of a set of characters
>   specified in an array from the current String object.

Before trimming the unwanted characters, you need to first identify whether the character is `Letter` Or `Digit`, if it is non-alphanumeric then you can use `String.Trim Method (Char[])` function to remove it.

you need to use Char.IsLetterOrDigit() function to identify wether the character is alphanumeric or not.

**From MSDN:** [`Char.IsLetterOrDigit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletterordigit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Indicates whether a Unicode character is categorized as a letter or a
>   decimal digit.

Try This:

```
string str = "()&*1@^#47*^#21%Littering aaaannnndóú(*&^1#*32%#**)7(#9&^";
foreach (char ch in str)
{
    if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch))
        str = str.Trim(ch);
}
```

**Output:**

```
1@^#47*^#21%Littering aaaannnndóú(*&^1#*32%#**)7(#9
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove any character which is not alphanumeric, you can use `IsLetterOrDigit` paired with a `Where` to go through every character. And because we're working at the `char` level, we'll need a little `Concat` at the end to bring everything back into a `string`.

```
string result = string.Concat(input.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit));
```

which you can easily convert into an extension method

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToAlphaNum(this string input)
    {
        return string.Concat(input.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit));
    }
}
```

that you can use like this :

```
string testString = "#!@!\"(test123)\"";
string result = testString.ToAlphaNum(); //test123
```

Note: this will remove every non-alphanumeric character from your string, if you really need to remove *only* those at the beginning/end, please add more details about what defines a beginning or an end and add more examples.

Answer (score 0):

And you could also replace all the non-letters/numbers at the beginning and/or end of the line:

```
^[^\p{L}\p{N}]*|[^\p{L}\p{N}]*$
```

used as

```
 resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"^[^\p{L}\p{N}]*|[^\p{L}\p{N}]*$", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

If you really want to only remove characters at the beginning and end of the "String" and not do this line by line, then remove the  ^$ match at linebreak option (RegexOption.Multiline)

If you wanted to include leading or trailing underscores, as characters to be retained, you could simplify the regex to:

```
^\W+|\W+$
```

The core of the regex:

```
[^\p{L}\p{N}]
```

is a negated character class which includes all of the characters in the Unicode class of Letters **\p{L}**  or Numbers **\p{N}**

In other words:

Trim non-unicode alphanumeric characters

```
^[^\p{L}\p{N}]*|[^\p{L}\p{N}]*$

Options: Case sensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn't match line breaks; ^$ match at line breaks; Parentheses capture

Match this alternative «^[^\p{L}\p{N}]*»
   Assert position at the beginning of a line «^»
   Match any single character NOT present in the list below «[^\p{L}\p{N}]*»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
      A character from the Unicode category “letter” «\p{L}»
      A character from the Unicode category “number” «\p{N}»
Or match this alternative «[^\p{L}\p{N}]*$»
   Match any single character NOT present in the list below «[^\p{L}\p{N}]*»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
      A character from the Unicode category “letter” «\p{L}»
      A character from the Unicode category “number” «\p{N}»
   Assert position at the end of a line «$»
```

Created with RegexBuddy

Answer (score 0):

Without using regex:
In Java, you could do: (in c# syntax would be nearly the same with same functionality)

```
while (true) {
    if (word.length() == 0) {
        return ""; // bad
    }

    if (!Character.isLetter(word.charAt(0))) {
        word = word.substring(1);
        continue; // so we are doing front first
    }
    if (!Character.isLetter(word.charAt(word.length()-1))) {
        word = word.substring(0, word.length()-1);
        continue; // then we are doing end
    }
    break; // if front is done, and end is done
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use this pattern

```
^[^[:alnum:]]+|[^[:alnum:]]+$
```

with `g` option
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oE6lE9)